# Semi-auto always better than bolt-action sniper rifle?

Tags: dead-island-riptide

In Dead Island Riptide, two new rifle types of firearms have been introduced: bolt-action and semi-auto sniper rifles.

Bolt-action sniper rifles can only be shot once before requiring another reload. It seems that on average, their accuracy, reload speed, and damage are lower than semi-automatic sniper rifles.

Semi-automatic sniper rifles hold about 5 ammo per magazine. Both seem to deal extra damage on head-shots.

Is there any reason to use a bolt-action sniper rifle over a semi-automatic sniper rifle?

Answer (score 1):

Stat-wise the semi auto is typically better than the bolt action. The bolt action does have one advantage. Killing docile drowners. In my 2nd playthrough the main use i had for any sniper rifle was to clear my path when wading through the flooded areas in the jungle. For some reason the bolt action is the only fire arm in the game that can do this. All other fire arms do not register thier hits on docile drowners.

Answer (score -1):

No there isn't, the Semi-Auto's tend to be better, which to me doesn't really make sense because a slower firing gun tends to be more accurate plus in games bolt actions usually tend to have more power

Comment: Why is the semi-auto better; do you have any proper evidence?